# How to hide all divs that are empty except the ones in a specific table

Tags: css

I have 10K lines of CSS that was written by a third party. It works great. I now have a third party control that I'm trying to use and this control has empty divs in it. Those empty divs are clickable and have background images. They do not have specific IDs or classes, however they are nested down in a table that has an ID.

The CSS has this in it: `div:empty { display:none !important; }`

Therefore my nested empty clickable divs with background images are not displayed.

Is there anyway to rewrite or add onto `div:empty { display:none !important; }` that will allow the divs to be displayed?

Comment: try body div:empty {display:block!important;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give more specificity to your `div:empty`

something like `class` or `id` before (depending on the parent) will work.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}
div:empty {
  display: none !important;
}
#parent div:empty {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div:empty { display: none !important;}    
div:empty { display: block !important;}
```

Display: block should work as long as the css is in this order

Comment: You have the same selector twice, both with `!important`, which means they have equal specificity and the last rule will always win.